# Copy multiple times of the same data according to the date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I need to write a macro to copy hostname and date to another workbook, the date need to be copied are in column B and AJ as hostname and date separately:

[image]

The way it's supposed to copy is like, if the date is Jan-2015, then I need to copy the hostname and date over another workbook 5 times (means have 5 rows of the same data), since June(6) minus Jan(1) is 5. If the date is Dec-2014, then I need to copy 6 rows of hostname and date since there are 6 months after December until June.

The final result will look like as shown below:
[image]

Now what I'm doing with VBA is put below, which is very ineffective and I couldn't make the macro put the rows of every date as expected, also I realize I have to do the if statement for every year, so I wonder how to make it more effective and make the macro run faster.

```
With wSheet1
    '// Here lets Find the last row of data
    wSlastRow = .Rows(.Range("B:B").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '// Now Loop through each row
    For X = 2 To wSlastRow
        'insert wSlastRow no of rows to worksheet Summary
        'wSheet1.Rows(wSlastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        If Not IsError(.Range("AJ" & X).Value) Then
            If IsDate(.Range("AJ" & X)) Then
                If Year(.Range("AJ" & X)) = 2015 Then
                    Do While Month(.Range("AJ" & X).Value) > 7
                        .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & X)
                        .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("J" & X)
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next X

End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only a couple of changes needed here; there are simpler ways to paste multiple rows but using your method of looping through, you only needed to use the DATEDIFF function to determine how many months were between dates, like so [Note that I refer to range("A1") below, to represent the place where you will type your June 2015 date. If the June 2015 comparison date appears elsewhere, change Range("A1") to something else]:

```
Sub Paste_Dates()

Dim wSlastRow As Integer
Dim wSLastPasteRow As Integer 'This will be used to check how far down has been copied thus far
Dim X As Integer
Dim NumberOfPasteRows As Integer 'This will store how many months there are between dates, to paste into
Dim PasteCounter As Integer

wSLastPasteRow = wSheet2.Rows(Sheets(2).Range("B:B").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With wSheet1

'// Here lets Find the last row of data
wSlastRow = 10 '.Rows(.Range("B:B").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'// Now Loop through each row
For X = 2 To wSlastRow

If Not IsError(.Range("AJ" & X).Value) Then
    If IsDate(.Range("AJ" & X)) Then

        NumberOfPasteRows = DateDiff("m", .Range("AJ" & X), .Range("A1"))
        'This finds the difference between your two dates in rounded months, and pastes for that number of rows
        'NOTE: A1 SHOULD BE REPLACED WITH WHATEVER DEFINES THE "JUNE 2015 COMPARISON"

        For PasteCounter = 1 To NumberOfPasteRows

            .Range("B" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow)
            .Range("AJ" & X).Copy Destination:=wSheet2.Range("AJ" & wSLastPasteRow)
            'Note - this used to paste to J; I have adjusted to now post to AJ

            wSLastPasteRow = wSLastPasteRow + 1
        Next PasteCounter

    End If
End If
Next X

End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can I replace .Range("A1") with June-2015? Since there are no cells contain this date

Comment: Now it works, but just it pasts starting from row 13304, which is the last row for the other column but column B itself, I already cleared all the table borders, color fills and values inside all cells for Column B. What do you think I miss out?